# Regular expression tags on multiple lines

Tags: python, html, regex

How to extract the contents between these tags when they're on multiple/ different lines?

```
<link>
https://widget.websta.me/rss/n/bleh
</link>
```

I tried:
    content = findall('(.*)', web_page_contents, re.DOTALL)
But I get the next mention of  instead of this one^

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/847552

Comment: Regular expressions are not suited for parsing XML unless it is very simple, i.e. regular :P You should use some xml handling library. For example read this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to do that. It has a very good [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and is very easy.

The following code will work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(webpage_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('link'):
    print link.text
```